# Is the MDN (and pretty much every other) reference to clip-path: path() wrong?

Tags: css

I am trying to do a very simple thing, to use clip-path with the path property, and making it scale to the whole size of the div containing it. I've researched more than just a little and in some places the *[geometry-box]* property gets mentioned, but I can't get it to work (I'm on chrome, v102.0.5005.61, last version at the time I think)... The code that I tried up until this point looks something like this one:

```css
.wholePage {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
  clip-path: border-box path('M0,0 L100,0 V90 Q 27 110 0 90');
}
```

```html
<div class="wholePage">
</div>
```

The thing is, without the *border-box* value, the path behaves in the way I expect it to (not scaling). But besides what some places say, adding the value *border-box* doesn't fix it (in chrome at least, it doesn't even recognize the property value with both path() and border-box). I know I could accomplish the result I'm looking for with a simple svg, but I want to understand the syntax of clip-path, and if it could be possible to make it scalable with just some other value.

Hope the question isn't too trivial :p thanks in advance to all willing to help me with this... I'll leave the [link to the mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) I was talking about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome just doesn't support `<geometry-box>` and there is an open issue for it in Chromium bug tracker:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=694218

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Jacob! 
I just tried it on a fairly recent firefox dev and it seems to not work either. I tried this syntax and others similar to this one (tried swapping the geometry-box value with path(), didn't work either). Am I doing something wrong?

Also, I am not used to the whole tracking issues on bug tracker platforms, do you think this will be fixed some time soon? Or in cases like this one it usually doesn't get fixed in, like, never?

Comment: @Figares I did a quick check on Safari because I am on MacOS, and unlike in Chrome it does *something*. I am not sure if it does the *right* thing. It will not get fixed any time soon, if you check the link, the issue has been created in 2017. I would say it's a cyclic dependency - it doesn't work so people don't use it and people don't use so  it doesn't get implemented.